# How to create knockout datagrid on popup from within datagrid

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I have a datagrid that has additional information I'd like to show in a pop up.

I display an icon to alert the user this information exists. The icon has a click action that performs a callback to the server to get this information. When I click this, I have all my data ready to view, but am not sure of the MVVM logistics of this.

Here is a mockup of what I'm trying to do. The alert function displays a modal popup. The click handler works, and the callback works fine.

I'm wondering, where do I create the new grid model, should it be a part of the current grid model, where do I apply bindings?

```
var initialData = [
    { name: "ABC", number: 1, icon: true},
    { name: "DEF", number: 2, icon: false },
];

var GridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "Name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "Number", rowText: "number" },
            { headerText: "Addl Info", 
              rowText: function (item) 
              {
                    return item.icon ? "<i class=\"icon\"></i>" : "";
              },
              clickHandler: function (item)
              {
                    function callback(data) {

                        // data is now an array of objects I want a data grid for that displays in the pop up.
                        alert("Additional Information", <HTML GOES HERE>);
                    }
                    $$.getJSON("url", [], callback);
              }
        ],
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new GridModel(initialData));
```